# Button not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I m using Jsf2 and Primefaces 3.5 ,this is my page header.inc.xhtml ,it s a modal dialog contient 2 buttons :

**header.xhtml**

```
 </h:head>
 <h:body>  
 <p:dialog id="modalDialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true"    height="100" visible="true">  
 <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
Nom :<font style="color: red">*</font>
<p:inputText  id="Nom" name="Nom" type="text"/>
<label  id="ErrorMessageLabel" style="color: red;display: none;">Champ obligatoire</label>
    <p:commandButton value="Recherche" type="button" icon="ui-icon-check" action ="#{collList.redirectToFiltrePage}"/>  
    <p:commandButton value="Annuler" type="button"  icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="dlg2.hide();" />       
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
</h:body> 
</ui:composition>
```

**CollBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="collist")
@SessionScoped
public class CollBean implements CollListBean {
.
.
.
public void redirectToFiltrePage() {        
    try {
    System.out.println("ça marche");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
}
```

Can someone help me plz, this button "Recherche" not working, have a nice day :) :)

Comment: Please don't kill questions by removing code where the question is all about. It would render questions unusable. If you'd like to remove/hide "sensitive" information then just edit/refactor/rename the code into SSCCE flavor. Additional bonus is, your question gets better this way.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the #{} around the method. And I'd use an actionListener since your method is void. It should be like this:

```
    <p:commandButton value="Recherche" type="button" icon="ui-icon-check" actionListener ="#{collaboratorList.redirectToFiltrePage}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Andre for the answer, for #{} is done it was just a a copying mistake. for actionListener not working either :( :(

Comment: Are you getting a validation error? That would prevent the method from being fired. As a quick test, remove the inputText and try again.

Comment: I don't get an error, I removed it and the same prob.I have also tried to do in action other thing like (action = "home.xhtml") but not working

Comment: All the primefaces components need to be inside a form tag (h:form) you're missing that.

Comment: update your question with the form markup so others can help more easily

Comment: En fait,the problematic line is here:
<p:commandButton type="button" ... />
'(type="button")' used to execute custom JavaScript and doesn't execute my action method